# Starting SMPP gateway

Tags: sms-gateway

From my previous question I felt adding a forwarder to SMPP gateway will be better. How can I start my own SMPP service? Do it requires any hardware? Do any experts here know about SMPP?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a VPS to install the SMPP Gateway you would like to use. There are few and optimal options to do this. Take a look to [Jasmin SMS Gateway](http://www.jasminsms.com/), it is still under development but the author uses it in production enviroment.

I work with a company that owns a powerfull SMPP Gateway with lots of functionalities, let me know if you are interested in something more 'pro'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *SMPP* is not that different from other protocols, and hardware requirements depend on how many concurrent users do you want to serve. You will need either a *VPS* or hardware server to run a *SMPP* service.

[Kannel](http://kannel.org/) is an open-source solution *SMPP* server and [here](http://kannel.org/overview.shtml#req) you can check its requirements.